# Deleting rows inside LazyVStack and ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

With a `List` one can simply use the `.onDelete` modifier to remove the rows from the List. But how can we do the same in a `ForEach` shown within a `LazyVStack`. I am using [SwipeCell](https://github.com/fatbobman/SwipeCell) to apply a drag gesture and showing a delete button but how do I actually remove from CoreData, specifically how do I access the `IndexSet` in this case

```
LazyVStack {
    ForEach(items) { item in
        Text("\(item.name)")
            .swipeCell(cellPosition: .right, leftSlot: nil, rightSlot: slot1)
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert){
                Alert(title: Text("Delete Task?"), message: nil, primaryButton:.destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {


                               // HOW DO I DELETE HERE ?


                               dismissDestructiveDelayButton()
                            }),secondaryButton: .cancel({dismissDestructiveDelayButton()}))
                        }
     }
}

private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833510/12299030? The idea is the same.

Comment: Any Update ?? If yes please post your ans.

Comment: This was helpful to me https://github.com/rick2785/Cart

Answer (score 20):

I've made a ViewModifier, that allows you to delete whatever view you want, with something similar to the Apple Animation.

When using, just call `.onDelete { //perform deletion }` on any View.

```
struct Delete: ViewModifier {
    
    let action: () -> Void
    
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var initialOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var willDeleteIfReleased = false
   
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2.bold())
                            .layoutPriority(-1)
                    }.frame(width: -offset.width)
                    .offset(x: geometry.size.width)
                    .onAppear {
                        contentWidth = geometry.size.width
                    }
                    .gesture(
                        TapGesture()
                            .onEnded {
                                delete()
                            }
                    )
                }
            )
            .offset(x: offset.width, y: 0)
            .gesture (
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        if gesture.translation.width + initialOffset.width <= 0 {
                            self.offset.width = gesture.translation.width + initialOffset.width
                        }
                        if self.offset.width < -deletionDistance && !willDeleteIfReleased {
                            hapticFeedback()
                            willDeleteIfReleased.toggle()
                        } else if offset.width > -deletionDistance && willDeleteIfReleased {
                            hapticFeedback()
                            willDeleteIfReleased.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        if offset.width < -deletionDistance {
                            delete()
                        } else if offset.width < -halfDeletionDistance {
                            offset.width = -tappableDeletionWidth
                            initialOffset.width = -tappableDeletionWidth
                        } else {
                            offset = .zero
                            initialOffset = .zero
                        }
                    }
            )
            .animation(.interactiveSpring())
    }
    
    private func delete() {
        offset.width = -contentWidth
        action()
    }
    
    private func hapticFeedback() {
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
        generator.impactOccurred()
    }
    
    //MARK: Constants
    
    let deletionDistance = CGFloat(200)
    let halfDeletionDistance = CGFloat(50)
    let tappableDeletionWidth = CGFloat(100)
    
    
}

extension View {
    
    func onDelete(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Delete(action: action))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm using this extension on a LazyVGrid with clear background on each row and you can always see the trash icon. Is there a way to toggle the opacity of it whenever you do a swipe action? So when you swipe left it appears and if you swipe right to cancel the deletion it will disappear?

Comment: @Mina maybe try putting the trash icon into an if statement and only show it, if the offset is less than 0 (or to be sure less than e.g. -5).

Comment: @Mina call `.background(Color.systemBackground)` (or whatever color you are sing) before `.onDelete { //perform deletion }`

Comment: @Mina you could add .clipped() after the .frame(...) modifier to make the icon only visible once the frame is expanded in width.

Comment: Really great. Is it possible to reset the previous swiping after a new swiping?

Answer (score 3):

I'm made some minor fixes, it works great.
function edited delete().

```
import SwiftUI

struct Delete: ViewModifier {

    let action: () -> Void
    
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var initialOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var willDeleteIfReleased = false
   
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .cornerRadius(radius: 7, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2.bold())
                            .layoutPriority(-1)
                    }
                    .frame(width: -offset.width)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle() )
                    .offset(x: geometry.size.width)
                    .onAppear {
                        contentWidth = geometry.size.width
                    }
                    .gesture(
                        TapGesture()
                            .onEnded {
                                delete()
                            }
                    )
                }
            )
            .offset(x: offset.width, y: 0)
            .gesture (
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        if gesture.translation.width + initialOffset.width <= 0 {
                            self.offset.width = gesture.translation.width + initialOffset.width
                        }
                        if self.offset.width < -deletionDistance && !willDeleteIfReleased {
                            hapticFeedback()
                            willDeleteIfReleased.toggle()
                        } else if offset.width > -deletionDistance && willDeleteIfReleased {
                            hapticFeedback()
                            willDeleteIfReleased.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        if offset.width < -deletionDistance {
                            delete()
                        } else if offset.width < -halfDeletionDistance {
                            offset.width = -tappableDeletionWidth
                            initialOffset.width = -tappableDeletionWidth
                        } else {
                            offset = .zero
                            initialOffset = .zero
                        }
                    }
            )
            .animation(.interactiveSpring())
    }
    
    private func delete() {
        //offset.width = -contentWidth
        
        offset = .zero
        initialOffset = .zero
        action()
    }
    
    private func hapticFeedback() {
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
        generator.impactOccurred()
    }
    
    //MARK: Constants
    
    let deletionDistance = CGFloat(200)
    let halfDeletionDistance = CGFloat(50)
    let tappableDeletionWidth = CGFloat(100)
    
    
}

extension View {
    
    func onDelete(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Delete(action: action))
    }
    func cornerRadius(radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: CornerRadiusStyle(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}

struct CornerRadiusShape: Shape {
   var radius = CGFloat.infinity
   var corners = UIRectCorner.allCorners

   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
     let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    return Path(path.cgPath)
   }
}

struct CornerRadiusStyle: ViewModifier {
   var radius: CGFloat
   var corners: UIRectCorner

   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
     content
        .clipShape(CornerRadiusShape(radius: radius, corners: corners))
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75841800/edit) your answer to highlight how it differs from the current accepted one.

Comment: `.cornerRadius(radius:,corners:)` is not a standard view modifier, you should include its implementation in your answer.

Comment: added remaining functions  .cornerRadius(radius:,corners:)

Comment: There's a whitespace above the Rectangle in ZStack