# How to swipe to delete in SwiftUI with only a ForEach and NOT a List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a custom list using a ForEach in SwiftUI.  My goal is to make a swipe to delete gesture and not embed the ForEach into a List.

This is my code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
let list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List{
            
            ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding()
                
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a gesture that will allow me to make a swipe to delete without using the list view.

I would also like to make a custom delete button what is shown when the user swipes an item to the left (like the below picture).

[image]

Comment: There is no specific out of the box "swipe to delete" gesture you can use. You'll have to use a `DragGesture` and implement the logic yourself. See some of the Kavsoft videos on YouTube for examples and I'm sure there are tutorials other places on the web.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting rows inside LazyVStack and ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103113/deleting-rows-inside-lazyvstack-and-foreach-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution for your problem. You should add `DragGesture` and create `offset` for each row.
Keep in mind that your variable declare by `var` can't be mutated. You have to add `@State` before.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]
    @State private var offsets = [CGSize](repeating: CGSize.zero, count: 6)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(list.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                
                HStack {
                Text(list[index])
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.list.remove(at: index)
                        self.offsets.remove(at: index)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    }
                }
                .padding(.trailing, -40)
                .offset(x: offsets[index].width)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.offsets[index] = gesture.translation
                            if offsets[index].width > 50 {
                                self.offsets[index] = .zero
                            }
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            if self.offsets[index].width < -100 {
                                self.list.remove(at: index)
                                self.offsets.remove(at: index)
                            }
                            else if self.offsets[index].width < -50 {
                                self.offsets[index].width = -50
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why using CGSize instead of just CGFloat for x?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the existing solution:

1. Added the same behaviour for swipe as it's in the List with animation.
2. Provided comments in the code to clearly understand what's going on there.

You can **update all constants at the top** to your values and it will work well. And also can update `.padding(.trailing, -40)` to your values (to hide the delete button by default).

```
struct SomeContentView: View {

@State var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]
@State var offsets = [CGSize](repeating: CGSize.zero, count: 6)

private let swipeLeftLimit: CGFloat = -50
private let swipeRightLimit: CGFloat = 50
private let swipeLeftLimitToShow: CGFloat = -30
private let swipeRightLimitToHide: CGFloat = 30

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(list.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            
            HStack {
            Text(list[index])
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.list.remove(at: index)
                    self.offsets.remove(at: index)
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                }
            }
            .padding(.trailing, -40)
            .offset(x: offsets[index].width)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        // Prevent swipe to the right in default position
                        if offsets[index].width == 0 && gesture.translation.width > 0 {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        // Prevent drag more than swipeLeftLimit points
                        if gesture.translation.width < swipeLeftLimit {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        // Prevent swipe againt to the left if it's already swiped
                        if offsets[index].width == swipeLeftLimit && gesture.translation.width < 0 {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        // If view already swiped to the left and we start dragging to the right
                        // Firstly will check if it's swiped left
                        if offsets[index].width >= swipeLeftLimit {
                            // And here checking if swiped to the right more than swipeRightLimit points
                            // If more - need to set the view to zero position
                            if gesture.translation.width > swipeRightLimit {
                                self.offsets[index] = .zero
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // Check if only swiping to the right - update distance by minus swipeLeftLimit points
                            if offsets[index].width != 0 && gesture.translation.width > 0 {
                                self.offsets[index] = .init(width: swipeLeftLimit + gesture.translation.width,
                                                            height: gesture.translation.height)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                            
                        self.offsets[index] = gesture.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { gesture in
                        withAnimation {
                            // Left swipe handle:
                            if self.offsets[index].width < swipeLeftLimitToShow {
                                self.offsets[index].width = swipeLeftLimit
                                return
                            }
                            if self.offsets[index].width < swipeLeftLimit {
                                self.offsets[index].width = swipeLeftLimit
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // Right swipe handle:
                            if gesture.translation.width > swipeRightLimitToHide {
                                self.offsets[index] = .zero
                                return
                            }
                            if gesture.translation.width < swipeRightLimitToHide {
                                self.offsets[index].width = swipeLeftLimit
                                return
                            }
                            
                            self.offsets[index] = .zero
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can easily move 'onChange' to the separate method `private func handleOnChangeGesture(_ gesture: DragGesture.Value, index: Int) {...paste code here...}` And the same separate method for 'onEnd'.