# How to use swipe actions without list and using indices swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Im making a todo app, and want a swipe to delete each task.

```swift
ScrollView { 
    ForEach(tasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
       TextField("Activity here", text: $tasks[index]) 
           .cornerRadius(20)
           .foregroundColor(textColor)
           .background(backgroundColor)
           .padding(.leading, 10)
           .padding(.trailing, 10)
           .padding(.top, 5)
       }
    }.frame(height: 600, alignment: .topLeading)
```

I’ve tried .onDelete and .swipeactions, but can’t figure out how to do it without a list.

Comment: You have to create your own

Comment: Using indices in a `ForEach` is a very dangerous practice. You should be using `Identifiable` data.

Comment: have a look at this [How to swipe to delete in SwiftUI with only a ForEach and NOT a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238383/how-to-swipe-to-delete-in-swiftui-with-only-a-foreach-and-not-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to use List for SwiftUI and you can use the onDelete to delete your tasks
Your code will be something like this:

```
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        List{
            
            ForEach(tasks.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                
                TextField("Activity here", text: $tasks[index])
                
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
            }
            .onDelete{_ in self.tasks.remove(at: 0)}
        }.frame(height: 600, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

However if you decide to create this app, but not in SwiftUI I can recommend for you 'SwipeCellKit' cocoapod.
https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit/blob/develop/Guides/Advanced.md
with tableviews you can create this app for cool. Good luck.