# SwiftUI custom delete button get IndexSet

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am implementing a custom delete button, without using List and .onDelete, however I can't seem to get the IndexSet of the row and couldn't find example of this anywhere.

CartView.swift

```
struct CartView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cartListVM = CartListViewModel()
    
    func deleteCart(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { index in
            let cart = cartListVM.carts[index]
            cartListVM.delete(cart)
        }
        cartListVM.getAllcarts()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(cartListVM.carts, id: \.id) { c in
                VStack {
                    Text(c.menuName)
                    Button(action: {
                        deleteCart(at: indexSet)
                        // Can't seem to get the IndexSet here, how?
                    }) {
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the indexset of the row? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a good workaround, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67357109/14675707).

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over the indices instead of the carts, so you can access each index. Then, just use `remove(at:)` to remove.

```
ForEach(cartListVM.carts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    VStack {
        Text(cartListVM.carts[index].menuName)
        Button(action: {
            cartListVM.carts.remove(at: index)
        }) {
            Text("Delete")
        }
    }
}
```