# ForEach onDelete is not working with LazyVStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

ForEach onDelete is not working with LazyVStack, but same code working fine with List. Any Idea ? Even swipe is not working here.

```
NavigationView {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 5) {
                
                Section(footer: ListFooterView()) {
                    ForEach(items.wrappedValue) { item in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            if  item.isNewItem {
                                NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item)) {
                                    ItemRowView(item: item)
                                }
                            }else {
                                NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: item)) {
                                    ItemRowView(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }.onDelete { offsets in
                        
                        let allItems = items
                        
                        for offset in offsets {
                            let item = allItems.wrappedValue[offset]
                            dataController.delete(item)
                        }
                        
                        dataController.save()
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: What you see in List is List feature, not `onDelete`. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833510/12299030?

Comment: I think onDelete is not List feature, it’s Foreach feature, ideally wherever we use Foreach, we should be able to use onDelete . If we see the documentation of ForEach it’s confirms to one protocol which has this Delegate function. This is my major doubt for posting this question.