# SwiftUI onDelete() without List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

Is it possible to have the `onDelete()` modifier on `ForEach` work without it being within a `List`?

e.g. in this example how could you get the default swipe to delete behaviour?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var numbers = [Int]()
    @State private var currentNumber = 1

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button("Add Number") {
                    self.numbers.append(self.currentNumber)
                    self.currentNumber += 1
                }
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.green.opacity(0.3))
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))
                }
                .onDelete { offsets in
                    numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833510/12299030?

Comment: No, I would still like to have the out of the box swipe to delete behaviour.

Comment: I think Swipe behavior is only available in List.

Comment: *out of the box* is a List feature, there is no such feature in ForEach.

Comment: Ok, then I will try to convert my `ScrollView` Layout to a `List` layout. Thank you.

Comment: This was helpful https://github.com/rick2785/Cart