# How to delete items in grid view (items saved in coredata)

Tags: swiftui

I can not delete items in grid view. When i tap edit button nothing happens. As I saw I can do it easily in list view but I need to it in grid view. I looked on the internet but I didn't see anyone trying to do it with coredata like me.

[image]

here is my code

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var recipes: FetchedResults<Recipe>
    
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160))]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text("\(recipes.count) \(recipes.count > 1 ? "recipes" : "recipe")")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
                        NavigationLink {
                            DetailView()
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                Image(.cake)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                
                                StrokeText(text: recipe.name ?? "", width: 1.0, color: .black.opacity(0.80))
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 0.0)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                    .padding(.top, -10)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 130)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 160, height: 220)
                            .background(.white.opacity(0.50))
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.4), radius: 15)
                            .padding(.vertical, 3)
                            .overlay {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 1.7)
                                    .frame(width: 160, height: 220)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteRecipes)
                }
                .padding([.bottom, .horizontal])
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Recipes")
            .background(.cyan.opacity(0.3))
            .toolbarBackground(.cyan.opacity(0.4), for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteRecipes(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let recipe = recipes[offset]
            moc.delete(recipe)
        }
        
        try? moc.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's what you are looking for: [Stackoverflow-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63824163/how-to-create-a-custom-delete-button-without-using-the-slide-to-delete-that-come/63833510#63833510)

Comment: @DennisHH I can't implement it in my code. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check within your `EditButton()` if  `.editMode` is `.active` and then `.overlay` and actual Button to you image, which will show if `.active` is true.
It looks like your `Edit-Button` work, but you missing an actual button to perform the delete.

For the next Time, please insert the complete Code. It is easier to help you.
The code for `EditButton` would be useful to see what's going on inside.